# Cleaning and preparind data for Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, kaggle

I am starting with Scala, Spark and MLlib.
I want to implement an example from a [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic)

The data format is awful and I have lots of problem cleaning and preparing the data to process them. I ask for your help.

The data is:

```
PassengerId,Survived,Pclass,Name,Sex,Age,SibSp,Parch,Ticket,Fare,Cabin,Embarked
1,0,3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",male,22,1,0,A/5 21171,7.25,,S
2,1,1,"Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)",female,38,1,0,PC 17599,71.2833,C85,C
3,1,3,"Heikkinen, Miss. Laina",female,26,0,0,STON/O2. 3101282,7.925,,S
4,1,1,"Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)",female,35,1,0,113803,53.1,C123,S
5,0,3,"Allen, Mr. William Henry",male,35,0,0,373450,8.05,,S
```

I got errors in the empty fields such as

> ...,"",... (first line, field "cabin")
>
> ...,"A/5 21171",.... (also first line, field "ticket")

I would like to filter the lines with empty fields (remove them from my RDD) and also those lines which have the ticket like this ***A/5 21171*** (I just want the number).

Thanks for your help again! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than `RDD`s, you should consider using `DataSet`s both for performance and ease of use--particularly if you are new to Scala. Taking the `DataSet` approach, you can do this:

```
val titanicDs = sparkSession.read
    .option("header", true)
    .csv("titanic.csv")
    .na
    .drop
    .withColumn("TicketSplit", split($"Ticket", " "))
    .withColumn("Ticket", when(size($"TicketSplit") === "2", $"TicketSplit".getItem(1)).otherwise($"TicketSplit".getItem(0)))
    .drop("TicketSplit")
```

There is a lot going on here:

- Set the `header` option to true so Spark realizes the first row is a header imposing structure on the data and uses those column names in the `DataFrame`.
- The `na` method returns a `DataFrameNaFunctions` object that is [very helpful](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions) for working with missing data. In this case, the combination of `na.drop` eliminates all rows containing *any* data that are `null`.
- I add a new temporary column called `TicketSplit` where I use the wonderful `functions` [library](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) to split the raw `Ticket` data on the space character into an array of either length 1 (if there is only a number) or 2 (if there is text followed by a space and number).
- I use `when` and `otherwise` from the `functions` library to modify the raw `Ticket` column according to the size of the array in the `TicketSplit` column. Whatever the size of the array in the `TicketSplit` column, ultimately only the number is preserved by either getting the first element of a 1-element array at index 0 or the second element of a 2-element array at index 1.
- Drop that `TicketSplit` column because it has served its purpose.
- Enjoy a nice cold drink.